# How to override / customize existing Widgets?

Tags: themes, widgets

I am quite new to Wordpress development and struggle to understand how to correctly override/customize an existing widget.

For example I have placed the *Recent-Posts* widget on a page. While it offers some options to customize its appearance (number of posts, grid vs. list, include image or not, etc.) I am far from having full control.

For example in grid layout a `<ul>` list with `<li>` elements is created. What if I want to use a ´` structure instead?

The styling options of the image are directly added HTML output and can thus not be modified in custom CSS. What if I want to use custom classes / styles instead?

**Is there any way to customize an existing widget on such a deep level or do I have to add my own widget to achive this?**

Comment: It probably depends on the specific widget and what hooks they give you for customisation.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no. Many widgets have action/ filter hooks where you can override certain pieces, but Widgets generally aren't like Themes which can be overidden with Child Themes.

Some widgets are written in such a way that they can be overridden, but that'd be on a case by case basis. Something like this you could declare the Class in an earlier hook and "override" the original.

```
if(!class_exists('My_Widget')) {
    class My_Widget extends WP_Widget {
       // ..
```

You'd need to read through the source code of the widget in question and see what options the author provides (or find the documentation if that's any good). [Here's the source for WP's Recent Post widget as an example](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-recent-posts.php).

Most likely your best bet is to [make a new Widget to suit your needs](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/widgets/), possibly extending the original or copy/paste it as a starting point if needed.